# Control de CheckBox Android Studio

Tags: android, checkbox

Buenas, he estado mirando por diferentes sitios de la web y no encuentro lo que intento hacer. Suena simple pero no acabo de saber como se hace.

La duda es la siguiente: En mi aplicación tengo 5 checkBox con diferentes temas (deporte, historia, biologia...) y un checkbox que es: Todos.

¿Como puedo hacer que cuando se checkee el checkbox de "Todos" se quiten todos los demas que esten checkeados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando crees los `checkBox` añadelos a un `ArrayList` de la siguiente manera:

```
//Iniciar un arraylist
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkArray = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
// añade tus checkbox a la lista
checkArray.add(aCheckBox);
```

Después en tu evento del click

```
for(i=0; i<checkArray.size(); i++)
{
    if (checkArray.get(i) != (CheckBox)v)  //  v es el parametro View que le pasas

       checkArray.get(i).setChecked(false);
}
```

Si no funciona hazmelo saber

Comment: Si, gracias, funciona correctamente!